# Secure way to pass a parameter from view to controller and returning it as a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parameter-passing

I'm looking for a secure alternative for querystring where I will pass a parameter to a controller method on the same controller and returning it as a view.

Categories View:

```
@foreach (Project.Framework.ModelClasses.productCategories productCategories in ViewBag.Categories)
    {           
        @Html.ActionLink(productCategories.description, "Products", "Shop", new { id = "", categoryID = productCategories.categoryID, description = productCategories.description }, null)
    }
```

Controller Method:

```
public ActionResult Products(string categoryID, string keyword, string description)
    {
        ViewBag.appPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appPath"].ToString();
        Methods Methods = new Methods();
        Methods.tokenHeader = (string)Session["token"];
        Methods.cookieContainer = (CookieContainer)Session["cookies"];

        Response shopnowProductsResponse = Methods.shopnowProductsGet(categoryID, keyword);
        if (shopnowProductsResponse.Code == "000")
        {
            List<product> products = new List<product>();
            products = (List<product>)shopnowProductsResponse.Data;

            string FPRFlag = "0";
            foreach (product product in products)
            {
                if (FPRFlag != "1")
                {
                    if (product.FPRFlag == "1")
                    {
                        FPRFlag = product.FPRFlag;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    goto nextState;
                }
            }
        nextState:

            ViewBag.FPRFlag = FPRFlag;
            ViewBag.Description = description;
            ViewBag.Products = products;
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Note: keyword is optional

Comment: What meaning of "secure" you use in your question? (maybe signing of the data would solve it?)

Comment: In particular, would it be secure enough if it were part of the URL other than the query string? By making it part of the route?

Comment: For security reasons I can't pass any parameter via URL because I'm passing sensitive data.

Comment: Define 'secure'.  Do you need it concealed from the user?  Concealed from someone monitoring traffic?  Do you need to be able to do integrity checks?  'Secure' means a lot of things.

Comment: If it is sensitive data then you should keep it server-side and put it in Session. By definition anything you send to the client (browser) is not secure. You could of course encrypt it but why go through all that trouble when you could just keep it server-side.

Comment: @Corey I need to conceal it from the users since they can learn from the URL.

Comment: @CraigW. I see. Can you provide a code snippet on how can I do it in session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you just want to encode those links in such a way that the end user can't scrape a list of all of your product data from the URLs, you can achieve this by using a substitute code in the link.  I'd use a hash value:

```
@foreach (Project.Framework.ModelClasses.productCategories category in ViewBag.Categories)
{
    @Html.ActionLink(category.description, "Products", "Shop", 
        new { 
            hc = category.categoryID.GetHashCode() 
        })
}
```

At the controller you then look up the hash code instead of the `categoryID`.

This still leaves two issues:

1. The hash code will be visible on the browser's address bar.
2. The list of hash codes will be the same every time.

The first one can be fixed with an intermediate action that translates the hash code back to a `categoryID` and stores the result in the `Session` store, then redirects to the `Products` page:

```
public ActionResult SetCategory(int hc)
{
    string catID = HashToCategoryID(hc);
    Session["categoryID"] = catID;
    return RedirectToAction("Products");
}
```

This not only puts the user's browser back to the `Products` page, it also makes sure (in most cases) that the `SetCategory` URL doesn't even show up in the browser history.  Generally the browser history won't even show that it navigated away from the `Products` page in the first place, so hitting the `Back` button will take them away from the page to wherever they were before they first came in.

The other issue - hash codes not changing - can be fixed a couple of ways: salting the hash with a value that will change from visit to visit (like the session ID) or generating random values and storing them in the `Session` storage for lookup.

For instance:

```
// after loading your products:

// something to salt the hash codes with:
string salt = (DateTime.Now - DateTime.Today).TotalMilliseconds.ToString();

// generate hash codes for all the product categories
var hashcodes = products.Select(p => new { h = (salt + p.categoryID).HashCode(), c = p.categoryID });

// create hash->categoryID dictionary and save in Session
var hashtocat = hashcodes.ToDictionary(hc => hc.h, hc => hc.c);
Session["HashToCategory"] = hashtocat;

// create categoryID->hash dictionary and save in ViewBag
var cattohash = hashcodes.ToDictionary(hc => hc.c, hc => hc.h);
ViewBag["CategoryToHash"] = cattohash;
```

Now each time the page is loaded you'll get a different set of hash values.  Your link generation then becomes:

```
@{ // grab hashcode dictionary from ViewBag
    Dictionary<string, int> hashcodes = ViewBag["CategoryToHash"] as Dictionary<string, int>;
}

@foreach (Project.Framework.ModelClasses.productCategories category in ViewBag.Categories)
{
    @Html.ActionLink(product.description, "SetCategory", new { hc = hashcodes[product.categoryID] })
}
```

Effectively you now have a list of single-use codes that expire and are replaced with new ones every time the user revisits the `Products` page.  The odds of getting the same code to work more than once for the same category are infinitesimal, and unless the link is clicked from the same session it will fail.

Speaking of fails... you'll need to add a bunch of error handling in there.

Comment: Before this reply. This is what have done in my project but without the use of hash. Thank you for your answer. Now I'm thinking if there is a possibility that the user from the browser can get inside of this method.

Comment: If you generate hashes or random keys for each page load then you're pretty safe.  At best they can list the hashes/keys generated for the current page, but that's not going to give them much information about your actual data structures.